# How to create an Apple Script that runs a Terminal command?

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to create an apple script that opens terminal and summons this command : `sudo killall coreaudiod`

How is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`do shell script "sudo killall coreaudiod" with administrator privileges`

the user gets asked for the password then

Comment: Create a `Run AppleScript` or `Run Shell Script` ?

Comment: automator could run the shell script directly though ;)

Comment: Can you check this please, it's related to your answer  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105150/a-turning-gear-appears-when-i-run-this-workflow-why